# Using a predefined Regex on a yank

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, yank

can you please help me to write a small emacs function? This is the first lisp function I am writing and I think I am getting confused with point and mark placement.

I want to write a function that yanks text and that than replace parts of it with a regular expression. 
Example:
I have in my killring

```
TEXT_TEXT
TEXT_TEXT
```

and I want in my buffer

```
TEXT_TEXT:10=TEXT_TEXT
TEXT_TEXT:10=TEXT_TEXT
```

These are the functions I have been writing. `query-replace-in-yank` does what I want, exept that I have to press `!` every time I use it. `replace-in-yank` is what I cant get to work.

```
(defun replace-in-yank (numstr)
  (interactive "sNumber: ")
  (let ((repstr (concat "\\1:" numstr "=\\1")))
    (let ((startp (point)))
      (yank nil)
       (let ((endp (point)))
          (goto-char startp)
          (while (re-search-forward "\\([A-Z\\_]+\\)" endp t)replace-match repstr t nil))))
   (newline-and-indent)))


(defun query-replace-in-yank (numstr)
 (interactive "sNumber: ")
 (let ((repstr (concat "\\1:" numstr "=\\1")))
  (yank nil)
  (exchange-point-and-mark nil)
  (query-replace-regexp "\\([A-Z\\_]+\\)" repstr  nil (mark) (point) nil nil))
 (newline-and-indent))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of your parens were in the wrong place. I think you were expecting `endp` to be updated when you do the `replace-match`, but it has a fixed value, so I changed it to use `copy-marker` instead, which will get updated.

```
(defun replace-in-yank (numstr)
  (interactive "sNumber: ")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((repstr (concat "\\1:" numstr "=\\1"))
          (startp (point)))
      (yank)
      (let ((endp (copy-marker (point))))
        (goto-char startp)
        (while (re-search-forward "\\([A-Z\\_]+\\)" endp t)
          (replace-match repstr t nil)))
      (newline-and-indent))))
```